# Compiling multiple typescript files separately

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I have 2 typescript files -

a.ts:

```
let some : string = "some";
```

b.ts:

```
console.log(some);
```

If I compile both files by adding them to include option in tsconfig (or by giving both on the command line), there is no error about some being undefined in b.ts. How can I compile both files separately? It doesn't even make sense for them to share namespace in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *namespace* in JavaScript. If you load the two compiled files in a browser (in the right order), the `console.log` will work. TypeScript reproduces this feature.

The JavaScript (and TypeScript) way is to use [ES6 *modules*](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/), for example with Webpack.

Your example with modules:

```
// a.ts
export let some = "some";

// b.ts
console.log(some); // Error here

// c.ts
import { some } from "./a"
console.log(some); // OK
```

Comment: Thanks.
One thing I want to do is be able to define same namespace in multiple files but still be able to refer variables (in the same namespace) in other files without using the namespace variable. Is it possible?

Comment: With [TypeScript _namespaces_](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html)? No, it's not possible. Namespaces are compiled to multiple IIFE, variables are accessible only in the local IIFE.